# twitter returns nothing when :max_id and/or :until are specified

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am using [`twitter` gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to retrieve tweets for the hash tag. My goal is to retrieve tweets for the last year. I am trying to use [`:max_id` option](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter%2FREST%2FSearch%3Asearch).

So, I do (`twitter` is properly configured client):

```
loop.inject(nil) do |memo|
  results = twitter.search "#ruby -rt", (memo ? {max_id: memo - 1} : {})
  last = results.inject(nil) do |_, res|
    # handle res here, unrelated
    res
  end

  break memo if last.nil? || last.created_at < (Date.today - 365).to_time
  last.id
end
```

The problem is that I receive an empty result set on *the subsequent request*. That said, the first request returns ≈2K tweets, the second always returns none.

How do I retrieve the statuses from twitter using `twitter` gem (or using anything else,) by chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that `max_id` parameter in call to `search` is [likely] expected to be a valid tweet id.

By changing

```
#                                                ⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE
twitter.search "#ruby -rt", (memo ? {max_id: memo - 1} : {})
```

to

```
twitter.search "#ruby -rt", (memo ? {max_id: memo} : {})
```

I was finally able to retrieve the feeds in the past by chunks.

**NB**: twitter responds with `RateLimit` error after each subsequent ≈1.5K statuses returned.